# HTML <select> stops firing onchange or onblur when iOS 11 Webview loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wkwebview

I am developing a Hybrid (web+native) app for iOS. The web part of the app is a SPA within a WKWebView (which is on a UINavigationController). The website has a `<select>` element with an `onchange`/`onblur` handler. When the user taps the `<select>` element, the native picker wheel appears. Then, when the user taps the Done button of the native picker, the `onchange` and `onblur` handlers are fired immediately. This all works as expected.

As this is a hybrid app, there are times when the app pushes a view controller on to the UINavigationController (on top of the web view). When that view controller is popped and focus is returned to the web view, everything appears to work as it did before.

However, the `<select>` elements will now only fire the `onchange` and `onblur` events when the user taps *away* from the element. If the user updates their selection and taps Done, the picker will dismiss but the value of the select element remains unchanged. Only after tapping outside of the element will the value update and the `onchange`/`onblur` events fire.

It doesn't matter when the new view controller is pushed and popped, even if it is before the `<select>` element has been created yet. If at any point during the web view's lifecycle it is covered up by a new view controller, this bug will occur 100% of the time until the webview is destroyed.

Sample code (nothing really special here):

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").onchange = function() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

This issue only occurs for iOS 11 and 12. Is it a bug specific to Mobile Safari? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using `<select onchange="console.log('hello');">`

Comment: No luck. The onchange handler itself works fine, it's just that Safari won't trigger it until tapping something else. Even without an onchange handler, the bug is still apparent since the value of the element won't change either.

Comment: This may be a bug because even in stackoverflow you have to click again. At least on safari

Comment: Experiencing the same problem, but intermittently. Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it? I've noticed that even text inputs aren't losing focus after pressing Done.

Comment: @Kevin_TA I haven't found a fix yet, sadly. I stopped looking into it since it's a relatively low priority issue. If I ever get back to it and figure it out, I will post an answer.

Comment: Having the same issue... tried a handful of workarounds with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found that if you add `optgroup`s to the select, the events seem to fire correctly. I've been appending empty ones to the select and that appears to be working for now.

Comment: I wonder if this is because looking at the [WebKit source code](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/ios/forms/WKFormSelectPicker.mm) each type of select has a different class. The bug is present in WKSelectSinglePicker, but not WKMultipleSelectPicker.

Comment: Another issue is that AutoLayout is actually broken in the native picker. When I debug on <= iOS 10 it's fine. Debug in >= iOS 11 and you get a broken constraint warning. I wonder if this related?